# bar chart of constant height for factors in time series

Tags: r

I am a beginner to try R for making graphs. Please help me. I have data of multiple columns (time series). Each column holds factors (please see the one column example data below). I would like to make a constant height (say 1 unit) bar chart of the time series and would like to represent “A” and “B” in different colors with the DATE on the x axis. Any tip?
Thanking you in advance!

```
DATE                      GROUP
2011.06.18 00:00:00         R
2011.06.18 06:00:00         L
2011.06.18 12:00:00         R
2011.06.18 18:00:00         R
2011.06.19 00:00:00         L
2011.06.19 06:00:00         L
2011.06.19 12:00:00         R
2011.06.19 18:00:00         L
2011.06.20 00:00:00         L
2011.06.20 06:00:00         L
2011.06.20 12:00:00         R
2011.06.20 18:00:00         L
2011.06.21 00:00:00         R
2011.06.21 06:00:00         L
```

Comment: What are A and B? At the moment, you have a factor L and R. Do you mean you have several columns like `GROUP`, each being an L or an R. You want to count up the Ls and Rs for each time point and show then as a stacked barchart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data are in `dat`, but with an extra column:

```
dat <- structure(list(DATE = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 0L, 6L, 
12L, 18L, 0L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 0L, 6L), mday = c(18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L), mon = c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), year = c(111L, 
111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
111L, 111L), wday = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), yday = c(168L, 168L, 168L, 168L, 169L, 169L, 
169L, 169L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 171L, 171L), isdst = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"
), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), GROUP = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("L", 
"R"), class = "factor"), GROUP2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("L", "R"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("DATE", 
"GROUP", "GROUP2"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then I think this does what you want. First count the elements == to one of the classes

```
counts <- apply(dat[, 2:3], 1, function(x) sum(x == "R"))
```

then compute the other count and bind to a matrix:

```
countmat <- t(cbind(L = (NCOL(dat) - 1) - counts, R = counts))
```

then we plot using `barplot()`

```
op <- par(mar = c(9,4,4,2) + 0.1, las = 2)
mids <- barplot(countmat, ylim = c(0,2.5),
                legend.text = c("L","R"),
                args.legend = list(x = "top", bty = "n"))
axis(side = 1, at = mids, labels = as.character(dat$DATE))
par(op)
```

which produces:

[image: barplot of time series]

See the help pages of the individual functions for explanations on the arguments.

**Edit:** If you just want to do this for an individual column, then this isn't the most interesting graph, but...

```
count2 <- with(dat, GROUP == "R")
countmat2 <- t(cbind(R = count2, L = !count2))

op <- par(mar = c(9,4,4,2) + 0.1, las = 2)
mids <- barplot(countmat2, ylim = c(0, 1.5),
                legend.text = c("R","L"),
                args.legend = list(x = "top", bty = "n"))
axis(side = 1, at = mids, labels = as.character(dat$DATE))
par(op)
```

which gives this figure:

[image]